# I want to know how to create a file from user inputs on a form in PHP

Tags: php, multiple-conditions

I want to know how to set user input conditions on a form in PHP. The condition are:
   If a user types in a name  and a drink  and it does not match   from a file called **drinks.txt which contains** 
   name, drinks
  tigerwoods, coke
  jay,sprite

it should append to and or create  a file called newdrinks.txt
 which stores 
    a) names and 
    b) drinks 
    c) ipaddress of the user

The code I have written is below but is not working.Note that I haven't posted my form code here just the php code I created. This form uses $_POST method.

```
   $as = file('drinks.txt');  
 foreach ($as as $line){

    $m = preg_split("/,/", $line);
}

if(!isset($_POST["u"]) && ($_POST["p"]) !== $m) {


echo " We don't have the drink Mr.$_POST[u] but we will make sure to get it next time";
$fp = fopen("drinks.txt", "a+");
$fwrite($fp, "newdrinks.txt");
fclose(($fp);
?>
```

Thank-you

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: You are doing your check after your loop, so you will only be checking against the last row/last time `$m` is set. Also you are missing your closing bracket `}` from you check, and you have a stray `$` at the beginning of `$fwrite(...)`, as `fwrite()` is a function, not a var.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a database?

Comment: I am new to php therefore doing some exercises in the book to practise. When I submit the form it doesn't append or create a file as instructed.

Comment: `$fwrite` - remove the dollar